# Parameters binding in bulk/batch insert within stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've encountered a problem with parameters binding and bulk inserting in SP. I have no idea why it's not working. According to docs it should work.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  COL1 NUMBER(38,0),
  COL2 NUMBER(38,0)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST()
RETURNS FLOAT NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "INSERT INTO TEST(COL1, COL2) VALUES(?, ?)",
    binds: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
});
stmt.execute();

return 0;
$$
;

CALL SP_TEST();

Execution error in store procedure SP_TEST: Unsupported type for binding 
argument 1,2 At Snowflake.createStatement, line 3 position 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any sample for entering multiple rows in [the documents](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-stored-procedures-binding-variables). In case, you want to use multiple values, then you can use the following syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST()
RETURNS FLOAT NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "INSERT INTO TEST(COL1, COL2) VALUES(?, ?),(?, ?)",
    binds: [1, 2, 3, 4]
});
stmt.execute();

return 0;
$$
;
```

As you can see, I removed the extra brackets in binds, and added a new "(?,?)" to the values part for the second row.

Comment: Thanks for an idea - it can be a solution for now.
Regarding dosc - there is an link in doc:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables - " Binding Statement Parameters" and it navigates to:
Binding Array for Bulk Insert.
But as i see, it is tagged as node.js so may be it differs from js in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TEST()
RETURNS FLOAT NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
    const vals = [[1, 2], [3,4]]
    const binds = vals.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
    const placeholders = vals.map(()=>"(?, ?)").join(",")
    const stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: "INSERT INTO TEST(COL1, COL2) VALUES " + placeholders,
        binds
    })
    stmt.execute()
    return 0
$$
```

The idea is to flatten the array, and then dynamically append the correct number of placeholders.